# Can't keep Kotlin and Java at the same version in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle

I have a problem with Gradle, just getting this error:

> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 19) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version

here is my Gradle file:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
id 'kotlin-parcelize'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
```

I've tried many solutions but have had no luck, so if there is any way to get back on the road again, I would much appreciate it.